# How to get country codes of the selected map area (visible map region)?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, country-codes

I want to get the country codes from the visible map region. Visible map region may contain multiple countries so I want all those country codes.

I've tried with Geocoder and with grid points in the map and it returned me all the country codes but the problem with that it's too slow. Geocoder takes time to return result so I'm looking for the alternate way.
Please help.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have tried so far. So that the community could check and help you better.

Answer (score 0):

The Maps JavaScript API provides a [Geocoder class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geocoder) for geocoding and reverse geocoding dynamically from user input. If instead you wish to geocode static, known addresses, see the [Geocoding web service.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding)